# Excel replace cell value if condition is met

Tags: excel

I have excel worksheet with many rows like the following:

```
  A        B       C(0)   D(1)   E(2)    F(3)  G(4)   H(5)  I(6)   J(7)
H'000C78:......):H'001D:H'002D:H'002D:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:
H'000C80:......):H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:H'002B:
```

I am interested only in the cell with value "H'002B".
The requirement is to get a list of values with the following condition:

If "H'002B" is found in any of the columns C-J then the cell containing "H'002B" is to be converted as A + Hex of value of that column.

For example:
1st row F column H'002B should become H'000C78 + H'3 = H'C7B.

The list which I want should have the first value as H'C7B.

Struggling a lot with it (by using HEX2DEC for all the values then writing a IF statement like =IF(C1="43","A1+0")).
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Edit your question to include your 'struggles' (working or not) and perhaps we can assist.

Comment: I have written what I was trying with. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the hex values 'in place' then some sort of VBA must be implemented. This short routine identifies and adjusts all occurrences of `H'002B` within the block of cells radiating out from Sheet1!A1.

```
Sub addHexColumn()
    Dim fnd As String, fndr As Range

    fnd = "H'002B"
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            Set fndr = .Cells.Find(What:=fnd, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            Do While Not fndr Is Nothing
                fndr = "H'" & Application.Dec2Hex(Application.Hex2Dec(Split(.Cells(fndr.Row, 1).Value2, Chr(39))(1)) + (fndr.Column - 3), 4)
                Set fndr = .FindNext(after:=fndr)
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This is roughly equivalent to applying the following formula to F1.

```
="H'"&DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,4))+COLUMN(F1)-3, 4)
```

This could possibly be further automated with the implementation of a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro or even a [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro but depending upon what the rest of the worksheet is doing it may not be an efficient expenditure of resources.

[image: add_column_hex_value]
                <sup>Sample data before addHexColumn sub</sup>

[image: add_column_hex_value_after]
                <sup>Sample data after addHexColumn sub</sup>

Comment: Why is F1 value becoming H'002E ? I expect it to become H'C78+H'2B = H'CA3

Comment: It seems that the maths are wrong. What part of the equivalent worksheet formula is incorrect? Can you correct the VBA code to compensate?

Comment: Math is not wrong. I think the formula is just doing H'2B + H'3 = H'2E. If only the formula can be changed as H'2B+H'C78=H'CA3.  I tried the vba but by workbook hung everytime.

Comment: So the formula should be `="H'"&DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,4))+COLUMN(F1)-3, 4)` where it takes the hex value from the first column. In that case, `fndr.Value2` in the maths should be `.Cells(fndr.Row, 1).Value2`.